# HTML code with no CSS support

Tags: html, forum

Here is the situation. I want to edit the HTML in my forum but there is no CSS support. I have included what I have, barring I didn't screw it up. What I want to do is put the three elements after the opening text side by side, in line. Next I want to do the same with the last to elements, the hit counters. My working knowledge is limited and I have tinkered to the last of my patience. I am a amateur, self taught, noob, whatever you want to call it so forgive my lack of knowledge.

```
<p>Click on the Iowa state icon to view members in your area of the state. To be placed on the map with what you are interested in finding click on the "Pop Smoke" icon and post your state, county and interest on the "local Patriots" group page. In order to view the Iowa Constitution click the Constitution icon.</p>

<p><a href="http://modernmilitiamovement.net/IOWA.html" target="_self" rel="nofollow"><img class="align-center" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/331lr0i.jpg" alt="" width="150"/></a></p>

<p><strong><strong><a href="http://modernmilitiamovement.com/group/local-patriots" target="_self" rel="nofollow"><img class="align-center" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/e5qw7l.png" alt="" width="125"/></a></strong></strong></p>

<p><a href="http://www.limitedgovernment.org/publications/IAConstitution.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="align-center" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/znrh28.jpg" alt="" width="200" border="0"/></a></p>

<p><a href="http://api.ning.com:80/files/nkvdZEQNy6zCn2jimzPD4qqESNX8HVjut48i5dAhMIf3v26qIZPzpAG6BqDSJKGk2ZV*G7wvlRG2*j3zCkGfOUKCqKyc83y1/alumbar.gif" target="_self"><img alt="" src="http://api.ning.com:80/files/nkvdZEQNy6zCn2jimzPD4qqESNX8HVjut48i5dAhMIf3v26qIZPzpAG6BqDSJKGk2ZV*G7wvlRG2*j3zCkGfOUKCqKyc83y1/alumbar.gif" width="540"/></a></p>

<p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.reliablecounter.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.reliablecounter.com/count.php?page=modernmilitiamovement.com/group/iowa-state-group&amp;digit=style/plain/6/&amp;reloads=1" alt="" title="" border="0"/></a><br/><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.reliablecounter.com" target="_blank" style="font-family: Geneva, Arial; font-size: 9px; color: #330010; text-decoration: none;">Unique visits</a></p>

<img src="http://www.reliablecounter.com/count.php?page=modernmilitiamovement.com/group/iowa-state-group3&amp;digit=style/plain/6/&amp;reloads=0" alt="" title="" border="0"/></a><br/> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.curinglight.com" target="_blank" style="font-family: Geneva, Arial; font-size: 9px; color: #330010; text-decoration: none;">All visits</a></p>
```

Comment: psst... *"style="font-family: Geneva, Arial; font-size: 9px; color: #330010; text-decoration: none;"* **is** CSS.

Comment: Understood. My point was there *is* CSS support. If inline styles work... then you can do anything you need to with CSS. Whomever told you "there's no CSS support" was wrong.

Comment: I was told that when I tried to add a background animation that relied on a CSS component. unless I am misquoting him and it was something else.

Comment: Well a background animation is just a HORRIBLE idea... but it's possible. You have inline styles. CSS absolutely **is** supported. You *may* have been told that because a background animation is just such a very, very bad idea.

Comment: why is a background animation such a bad idea?

Comment: It's annoying and distracting to viewers and serves no actual purpose other than to make people *leave* the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using inline style *("style=...")* already. Paragraph elements display "block" by default, which means they will each start a new line and span the the entire width available to them.

I'd suggest wrapping each set of tags you want vertically aligned together in a *div* and either change the display styling of your paragraphs or remove some of them.

Comment: I think I used a bad choice of words in using "in line". I mean that they would simply display next to each other.